# jQuery deferred error: cannot read property 'then' of udefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am trying to cache the values of an array before using it in my whole program.I am using jQuery deferred objects.  I thought I understood the concept but it looks like I might be missing a puzzle piece.  Please see code below. I get the error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'**

What am I doing wrong?

```
var cacheNavData = [];
var cacheSubNavData = [];
var cacheMegaMenuData = [];
var cacheCategoryMenuData = [];


getSubNavData();
getMegaMenuData();
getCategoryMenuData();

function getNavData(){
     var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
  console.log(dfd)

     setTimeout(function(){ 
      cacheNavData[0] = "Soup";
      cacheNavData[1] = "Sandwich";
      cacheNavData[2] = "Rice";

     return dfd.resolve(cacheNavData);
     }, 3000);
 }

 function getSubNavData(){
     var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();

     setTimeout(function(){ 
      cacheSubNavData[0] = "Apple";
      cacheSubNavData[1] = "Beans";
      cacheSubNavData[2] = "Carrot";

      return dfd.resolve(cacheSubNavData);
    }, 3000);
 }

 function getMegaMenuData(){
     var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();

      setTimeout(function(){ 
      cacheMegaMenuData[0] = "Donkey";
      cacheMegaMenuData[1] = "Eagle";
      cacheMegaMenuData[2] = "Frog";

      return dfd.resolve(cacheMegaMenuData);
     }, 3000);
}

function getCategoryMenuData(){
     var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();

     setTimeout(function(){ 
      cacheCategoryMenuData[0] = "Grapes";
      cacheCategoryMenuData[1] = "Hand";
      cacheCategoryMenuData[2] = "Igloo"; 

     return dfd.resolve(cacheCategoryMenuData);
     }, 3000);
 }

 function createNavigation(){
   console.log("All arrays have been populated.  Let's build the navigation.")
 }

var promise = getNavData();

promise.then(getSubNavData).then(getMegaMenuData).then(getCategoryMenuData).done(function(){
  createNavigation();

 console.log(cacheNavData);
 console.log(cacheSubNavData);
 console.log(cacheMegaMenuData);
 console.log(cacheCategoryMenuData);
})
```

[pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/xxGxMZr?editors=0012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var cacheNavData = [];
var cacheSubNavData = [];
var cacheMegaMenuData = [];
var cacheCategoryMenuData = [];


getSubNavData();
getMegaMenuData();
getCategoryMenuData();

function getNavData(){
     var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
  

     setTimeout(function(){ 
      cacheNavData[0] = "Soup";
      cacheNavData[1] = "Sandwich";
      cacheNavData[2] = "Rice";

      dfd.resolve(cacheNavData);
     }, 3000);
  return dfd;
 }


 function getSubNavData(){
     var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();

     setTimeout(function(){ 
      cacheSubNavData[0] = "Apple";
      cacheSubNavData[1] = "Beans";
      cacheSubNavData[2] = "Carrot";

       dfd.resolve(cacheSubNavData);
    }, 3000);
   return dfd;
 }

 function getMegaMenuData(){
     var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();

      setTimeout(function(){ 
      cacheMegaMenuData[0] = "Donkey";
      cacheMegaMenuData[1] = "Eagle";
      cacheMegaMenuData[2] = "Frog";

       dfd.resolve(cacheMegaMenuData);
     }, 3000);
   return dfd;
}

function getCategoryMenuData(){
     var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();

     setTimeout(function(){ 
      cacheCategoryMenuData[0] = "Grapes";
      cacheCategoryMenuData[1] = "Hand";
      cacheCategoryMenuData[2] = "Igloo"; 

      dfd.resolve(cacheCategoryMenuData);
     }, 3000);
  return dfd;
 }

 function createNavigation(){
   console.log("All arrays have been populated.  Let's build the navigation.")
 }

var promise = getNavData();

promise.then(getSubNavData).then(getMegaMenuData).then(getCategoryMenuData).done(function(){
  createNavigation();

 console.log(cacheNavData);
 console.log(cacheSubNavData);
 console.log(cacheMegaMenuData);
 console.log(cacheCategoryMenuData);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Think you missed the return of promise:-

```
function getNavData(){
 var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();


 setTimeout(function(){ 
  cacheNavData[0] = "Soup";
  cacheNavData[1] = "Sandwich";
  cacheNavData[2] = "Rice";

 return dfd.resolve(cacheNavData);
 }, 3000);
 return dfd;
}
```

Comment: Now I'm confused, where is the following being returned to?  ``` return dfd.resolve(cacheNavData);```

Comment: Do I need to resolve in just one function?  The return dfd in just one function seems to have worked for all the functions.

Comment: in fact you dont need to return the resolve just returning the promise will suffice.

Comment: When I don't return resolve, createNavigation() never gets called.